# Register a domain name

Tags: domains, webserver

Hello I am new at this and so i've come on here hoping I would get some answers. I would like to register a domain name and I already have a hosting site, so I would have to just make sure I change the DNS to the new hosting site. Can anyone tell me where I can go to just get a domain name ONLY without having to use their hosting since I already have another company hosting. I also need it to be affordable also.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a *domain name registrar*. You can find a list of them by searching for '[domain name registrar](https://www.google.com/search?q=domain+name+registrar)' on Google. Any registrar should let you register a domain without having to pay for hosting.

Comment: FWIW: I recommend [NameCheap](http://www.namecheap.com/).